# jQuery bind table row inputs

Tags: jquery, bind, rows

I'm not very experienced javascript developer and I can't figure out how to bind inputs in each table row.

My table has three columns - **start**, **progress** and **remain**. Start column contains static value of time estimation and other two columns contains inputs of progress and remaining time. I need to bind those inputs so that progress or remain input is recalculated when the other one changes, according to this expression: **start = progress + remain**.

Here's where I got so far..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Peracek/gkgoxjgd/2/)

html:

```
<table class="stats">
    <thead>
        <td>estimation</td>
        <td>progress</td>
        <td>remain</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="estimation">50</td>
            <td class="progress"><input type="number" value="20"/></td>
            <td class="remain"><input type="number" value="30"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="estimation">100</td>
            <td class="progress"><input type="number" value="10"/></td>
            <td class="remain"><input type="number" value="90"/></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="estimation">70</td>
            <td class="progress"><input type="number" value="20"/></td>
            <td class="remain"><input type="number" value="50"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
//array of rowClasses
var rows = [];

var rowClass = function(row){
    this.$row = $(row);
    this.$estimation = this.$row.find('.estimation');
    this.$progress = this.$row.find('.progress');
    this.$remain = this.$row.find('.remain');
};

//jquery collecion of table rows
var $rows = $("table.stats>tbody>tr");

//populate rows array with rowClasses
$rows.each(function(index){
    rows[rows.length] = new rowClass($rows[index]);
});
```

I don't know to include jQuery .change() function, so it refers to related row values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add min & max value for input field as value should remain in range.

```
<tr>
    <td class="estimation">50</td>
    <td class="progress">
        <input type="number" value="20" min="0" max="50"/>
    </td>
    <td class="remain">
        <input type="number" value="30" min="0" max="50"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then add following script below your javascript, that will perform calculation:

```
$("td.progress input, td.remain input").bind('keyup mouseup', function() {

    var tdEst = $(this).parent().parent().children()[0];

    if ($(this).parent().prop('class') == "progress") {
        var tdRem = $(this).parent().next('td.remain');
        var remValue = parseInt($(tdEst).html()) - parseInt($(this).val());
        $(tdRem).find('input').val(remValue);
    } else {
        var tdProg = $(this).parent().prev('td.progress');
        var remValue = parseInt($(tdEst).html()) - parseInt($(this).val());
        $(tdProg).find('input').val(remValue);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hvxp5vf/)

Comment: I was looking for more OO solution, but this works as well:) Thanks